# Reverse for 'about_me' not found. 'about_me' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-templates

What's happening. I still have trouble displaying the title list. Where did I make a mistake?

views.py

```py
        def dashboard(request):
            bookmarks = Text_field.objects.order_by('created')
            return render(request, 'Site/dashboard.html', {'bookmarks': bookmarks})

        def about_me(request, pk):
            about = get_object_or_404(Text_field, pk=pk)
            return render(request, 'Site/about_me.html', {'about': about})
```

dashboard.html

```py
    {% extends "Site/base.html" %}
    {% load static %}


    {% block content %}
        {% for bookmark in bookmarks %}
        <div>
          <p>Stworzono dn. {{ bookmark.created }}</p>
          <h1><a href="{% url "about_me" pk=about.pk %}">{{ bookmark.title }}</a></h1>
          <p>{{ bookmark.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```py
        path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
        path('about/<int:pk>/', views.about_me, name='about_me'),
```

Comment: Did you specify an `app_name` in your `urls.py`?

Comment: It is `app_name = 'Site'`

Comment: The the url is `{% url 'Site:about_me' pk=about.pk %}`.

Answer (score 0):

In your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662677/reverse-for-about-me-not-found-about-me-is-not-a-valid-view-function-or-pat/57662893#comment101774422_57662677) you say you defined an `app_name` in your `urls.py`, you need to include that `app_name` in your `{% url ... %}` name:

```
{% url 'Site:about_me' pk=bookmark.pk %}
```

Comment: It Works! :3
But there was another problem... pk should have `pk=bookmark.pk` :)
Thx Willem Van Onsem!